# Unix cut in c shell

Tags: cut, csh

in file ~/x,

--- //zep/arod/jo/new/ded/main/changes  2013-05-13 17:14:34.000000000 -0700
--- //zep/arod/jo/new/ded/main/lib/soph/tool.py  2013-05-16 14:14:34.000000000 -0700
--- //zep/arod/jo/new/ded/main/lib/soph/pomp.py  2013-05-16 14:14:34.000000000 -0700

in c shell,

```
set F=`grep '^---' ~/x | cut -d/ -f7-99 | cut and somehow cut number`
```

then, `ls $F` should give

ded/main/changes
ded/main/lib/soph/tool.py
ded/main/lib/soph/pomp.py

I dont quite understand the -f tag and not sure how to cut the timestamp part

any suggestions?

Comment: Somehow `awk '/^---/{ sub(/\/\/zep\/arod\/jo\/new\//,""); print $2 }' ~/x` seems more straightforward.

Comment: yes i was looking into either awk or sed but i am really not familiar with those. @tripleee but ill stick with grep and cut for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-f7-99` means "include fields 7 through 99" (which in this case, they probably just meant `-f7-` which would give all fields 7 and up).

`cut` divides each line up into fields, based on the divider (which is what `-d/` is specifying - the divider in that case is the `/` character). It then returns the fields that you ask it for (in your example, 7 through 99).

Your second cut command could probably be `cut -d' ' -f1` which would use a divider of spaces and only give you the first field (in other words, everything before the first space, which would be just the path).

Comment: yes. you are right. on the second part of the cut, what would be the best way to only cut the timestamp part 2013-05.............

Comment: is it possible to -d by space maybe?

Comment: ah ok let me try that

Comment: ah that worked except the space between the text and 2013 is actually a tab. isnt -d default to tab? so cut -d -f1 should get rid of the anything that after tab?

Comment: hmm it says cut: the dlimiter must be a single char for cut -d -f1 part

Comment: You could just omit the `-d` entirely if you want tabs.

Comment: oh thats what they meant by default. omitting the use of the option.